# iOS In-app purchase in multi user app

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, multi-user, in-app-subscription

I just run into a problem with in-app auto-renewable subscription. The app contains this kind of subscription and the app can be used by multiple users but the subscription is bind to the apple id is used on the device. So if a different user log in to the app than the system say he has a valid subscription. If I log the subscribed users on my backend server than if a user without subscription log into the app can not make a new subscription according to the Apple's response because the apple id used on the device. An other problem if a keep track of the subscriptions on my backend server if the user unsubscribe on the apple's webpage I can't notify the server about if.

What do I do wrong? What is the right workflow for this case?

I hope do you understand my dilemma.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is absolutely valid and that's exactly how the subscriptions In-App purchase work with any platform (Apple/Google).

In case of Subscriptions in-app purchase the content delivery is entirely the responsibility of the app provider and not the platform. You have no direct way of identifying if the app user has been switched to a different user as you can't access the current logged in user on iTunes account on the device.

You need to manage this use case on your own by keeping some data locally on the device and maintain user purchase history but still that wouldn't solve the purpose 100%. When user will go for purchase of the subscription it will show the service as already subscribed unless the iTunes user account is also switched on the device.

You can keep track of the unsubscribed state from the backend as when the subscription is successful you will get a receipt from iTunes which you can use to save in your DB. You need to run a backend job on the server side to validate the saved receipt to check the updated receipt which will give you details if the subscription has been expired or not.

Comment: Rephrasing the problem is not an answer :-)

Comment: Posting the problem, without understanding the platform fundamentals is a bad development practice :)

Comment: I consider not understanding something as the most valid reason to post a question.